# How can I place a button control group within a field container?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a control group of buttons that looks like this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label>Ahead</label>
  <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Hour</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Day</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Week</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Month</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like for the label to look like the rest of the labels in my form.  As you can see, the label is not inline with the control group as it is with other controls:

[image: Fieldcontain]

How do I wrap a control group in a field container and have the label appear inline?  Is it possible?  I didn't see any examples of this on the jqmobile site.

The entire markup for the form is:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-native-1">Metric</label>
    <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
      <asp:Repeater ID="ui_metrics" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <option value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "friendly_name")%></option>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </select>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="select-native-1">Interval</label>
      <select name="select-native-1" id="select1">
        <asp:Repeater ID="ui_interval" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <option value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "friendly_name")%></option>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="datetime-4">Start Date</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime-4" id="datetime-4" value="" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label>Ahead</label>
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Hour</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Day</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Week</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Month</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <div data-role="rangeslider">
        <label for="range-7a">Index:</label>
        <input type="range" name="range-7a" id="range-7a" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <label for="range-7b">Index:</label>
        <input type="range" name="range-7b" id="range-7b" min="0" max="100" value="100" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add rest of your HTML and I will fix it for you.

Comment: how are you controlling the position of other labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/64/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="custom-fieldcontain">
    <label>Ahead</label>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Hour</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Day</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Week</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Month</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
@media all and (min-width: 28em){
    #custom-fieldcontain label {
        width: 22% !important;    
        display: inline-block;    
    }

    #custom-fieldcontain [data-role=controlgroup] {
        width: 78% !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #custom-fieldcontain [data-role=controlgroup] .ui-controlgroup-controls {
        width: 100% !important;        
    }    

    #custom-fieldcontain [data-role=controlgroup] .ui-controlgroup-controls a {
        width: 24.5% !important;
    }    
}
```

### Info

Working example was made using your HTML. Media queries are used directly from jQuery Mobile css file. Rest of CSS is a label fix / content fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example without customizing the fieldcontainer...

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Ahead</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="hour" checked="checked">
        <label for="hour">Hour</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="day"> 
        <label for="day">Day</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="week"> 
        <label for="week">Week</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="month"> 
        <label for="month">Month</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They dont stand in the same line because `div` with `controlgroup` is a block element. You could use one of the two solutions which I've used before :

## Solution 1 : Using CSS to achieve the inline look

**Solution**

Just add a `display: inline` property to the control group, you're good to go.

```
[data-role=controlgroup] {
    padding-left : 2em;
    display: inline;
}
```

**Note**

The CSS selector I've used is just an indicator. Try using ID for the control group you want to change. Also, make sure that the custom style you are adding is loaded after jQM's style. **To adjust the seperation between label and buttons, change the `padding-left` to your hearts' content.**

## Solution 2: Using grids to set up the layout

Grids provide a good way to arrange elements in jQM. A typical grid layoud would look like this :

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

This is a typical 2-column layout, which we'd use here as well. So here's how your layout must look like :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:20%">
            <label>Ahead</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:70%">
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Hour</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Day</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Week</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Month</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**

You could adjust the width of the `ui-block-*` elements to any size you need by changing **the width property** in the HTML tag.

## A consolidated Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bGjZ8/2/

Comment: Though that puts the label inline, it doesn't behave like the rest of the labels.  See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lFnIu.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/boY2z.png)